# Calculating center line of curved pipe

Tags: circles, 3d

I want to have have a disk move vertically through a curved pipe. The pipe shape and size will be constant, the overall position and rotation in a 3d space will be random. Is it possible to calculate the centerline of this pipe piece to act as a path for the disk? Is there a function that takes the pipe's position and rotation, and the disk's current position and rotation, and returns where the disk should move to in the next frame?

Here are some instances of the pipes orientation in a 3d space:
[image]

Here are the measurements of the curved pipe and the circles that define it: 
The pipe is a 30 degree turn.
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:elliptic-curves], albeit the tag description is a bit ambiguous if you do not know what they are.

Comment: What would be the proper tag for this then?